# Is this really a Dahlia tuber?

Tags: identification

I dug Dahlias today and I was pretty sure this clump that I dug was one of my dahlias.  However, what I uncovered does not look like any dahlia tuber I have seen?  There were several of these and each had a hollow dahlia like stem. If it is not a dahlia, what might it be?  I guess I will find out when I replant them next spring, but I would like to know now.  I suppose I could not be remembering what was growing in that spot this past summer, but it was right in a row with other dahlias, and I cannot remember that anything else was growing there.  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not a dahlia; their tubers are roundish or cylindrical and chubby this time of year. They look rather like potatoes, but clumped around the base of the stem.

I can't even guess what that plant is, but can rule out Jerusalem artichokes and most of the Aster family.

Comment: Thanks Jurp.  Someone said they looked like runners but they are not.  Those roots were growing straight down into the depths, not horizontally.